# Significato di "piangere sulla brocca rotta"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Il contesto*, di Leonardo Sciascia, ho letto:

> "Ma, dico, io **non sto mai a piangere o a infuriarmi sulla brocca rotta**. E poi gli errori a volte producono effetti che, anche se diversi di quelli che si volevano conseguire, tornano di insperata utilità. [...]"

La mia domanda è sulla frase "non sto mai a piangere o a infuriarmi sulla brocca rotta" che appare in questo brano. Si tratta o fa riferimento a qualche modo di dire o frase fatta? Cosa vuol dire esattamente? Ho cercato alla voce "brocca" in parecchi dizionari, incluso il dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Piangere](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piangere/) sulla brocca rotta** è simile al modo di dire **piangere sul latte versato**, cioè rimuginare inutilmente su una situazione che non si può più cambiare.

> p. sul latte versato, pentirsi troppo tardi di aver commesso uno
>   sbaglio, un errore;

È interessante [l'origine dell'espressione](http://perchesidice.libreriamo.it/perche-si-dice/perche-si-dice-e-inutile-piangere-sul-latte-versato/):

> Il significato di questa espressione vuol dire che è inutile
>   disperarsi e lamentarsi dopo aver commesso degli errori che non si
>   possono annullare e riparare, è inutile rimuginare su cose che sono
>   oramai accadute, tormentandosi quando praticamente è troppo tardi.
>
> Probabilmente questo proverbio ha origini molto antiche, ai tempi
>   antecedenti alla produzione industriale quando il latte era
>   considerato un alimento raro, costoso e prezioso alla nutrizione, per
>   cui, il suo spreco poteva arrecare dei forti rimorsi.